# Insert layer using Arcpy- Code error

Tags: arcpy, layers

I'm trying to add "roads" layer to all the maps that do not have this layer in the table of content, by using this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,fnmatch
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
insertLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"G:\desktop\Project\layers\roads.lyr")
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    refLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "residence", df)[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
        if 'roads' not in lyr.name:
            arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, insertLayer, "BEFORE")
            print 'InsertLayer'
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

I get unwanted result- the layer copied several times each map, while i want that the 'roads' layer will be inserted just one time for each map:

```
>>> 
landUse.mxd
InsertLayer
InsertLayer
InsertLayer
project.mxd
InsertLayer
InsertLayer
>>>
```

I asked this question already in [How to insert layer excluding MXD files using arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192984/how-to-insert-layer-excluding-mxd-files-using-arcpy) and got answer that include lambda code line. I need code without lambda code line because of default system

Comment: If script with lambda code line works, it's good idea to understand why, this would of help you with your version of code. -1 btw, no efforts on your side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert layer excluding MXD files using arcpy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192984/how-to-insert-layer-excluding-mxd-files-using-arcpy)

Comment: If you have a problem like this that occurs in every iteration of your MXDs then I think the logical thing to do is to remove the iteration to make a smaller code snippet that focuses on what happens with a single MXD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you add the layer within each step of the loop when you check if the lyer name exists. In fact you add road once for each layer that is not "road". Remove the loop and it should work.

```
import arcpy,os,sys,fnmatch
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
insertLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"G:\desktop\Project\layers\roads.lyr")
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    refLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "residence", df)[0]

    if 'roads' not in [x.name for x in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df)]:
        arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, insertLayer, "BEFORE")
        print 'InsertLayer'
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```